# Python forward stepwise regression 'Not in Index'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, statsmodels

I am running some tutorials on the Boston Housing Data, with the help of a couple forward stepwise examples online. I keep getting an error that one of the variables is not in index.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as  pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston_dataset = load_boston()

#create dataframe from boston
X = pd.DataFrame(boston_dataset.data, columns = boston_dataset.feature_names)
y = boston_dataset.target


#split data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=5)
```

Here is the regression loop, used from [this](https://www.datasklr.com/ols-least-squares-regression/variable-selection) website, there is also a nearly identical slice of code [here](https://github.com/AakkashVijayakumar/stepwise-regression/blob/master/stepwise_regression/step_reg.py):

```
def forward_regression(X, y,
                       initial_list=[], 
                       threshold_in=0.01, 
                       threshold_out = 0.05, 
                       verbose=True):
    initial_list = []
    included = list(initial_list)
    while True:
        changed=False
        # forward step
        excluded = list(set(X.columns)-set(included))
        new_pval = pd.Series(index=excluded)
        for new_column in excluded:
            model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(pd.DataFrame(X[included+[new_column]]))).fit()
            new_pval[new_column] = model.pvalues[new_column]
        best_pval = new_pval.min()
        if best_pval < threshold_in:
            best_feature = new_pval.argmin()
            included.append(best_feature)
            changed=True
            if verbose:
                print('Add   with p-value '.format(best_feature, best_pval))

        if not changed:
            break

    return included
```

Once I run
`forward_regression (X_train, Y_train)`, I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: what's the shape of `X` and `Y`?

Comment: x: (404, 13)  y: (404,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `idxmin()` in place of `argmin()`.  The latter is returning the integer location while `idxmin()` will return the label.

The fixed function is

```py
def forward_regression(X, y,
                       initial_list=[], 
                       threshold_in=0.01, 
                       threshold_out = 0.05, 
                       verbose=True):
    initial_list = []
    included = list(initial_list)
    while True:
        changed=False
        # forward step
        excluded = list(set(X.columns)-set(included))
        new_pval = pd.Series(index=excluded)
        for new_column in excluded:
            model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(pd.DataFrame(X[included+[new_column]]))).fit()
            new_pval[new_column] = model.pvalues[new_column]
        best_pval = new_pval.min()
        if best_pval < threshold_in:
            # Change argmin -> idxmin
            best_feature = new_pval.idxmin()
            included.append(best_feature)
            changed=True
            if verbose:
                print('Add   with p-value '.format(best_feature, best_pval))

        if not changed:
            break

    return included
```